# VBA shorthand for x=x+1?

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Sub btn1_Click()
Static value As Integer
value = value + 1
MsgBox value
End Sub
```

I swear when I was taking a VB.net course in college there was a shorter way to tell a variable to add '' to itself. Maybe x=+1. I am using Access now though instead of visual studio. When I try that within the VBE it removes the +. I even removed `Option Explicit` with no change

Assuming the answer will be no, there is no way to short-hand it & its just a peculiarly of VBA

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Sadly there are no `operation-assignment` operators in VBA.

(Addition-assignment `+=` are available in VB.Net)

Pointless workaround;

```
Sub Inc(ByRef i As Integer)
   i = i + 1  
End Sub
...
Static value As Integer
inc value
inc value
```

Comment: +1 coming from a cpp background I remember asking myself this question the first day I picked up VBA and doing the exact same pointless workaround haha

Comment: One should note that `inc` should be a `Sub` as in this case the `Function`'s return value is discarded and not needed. Declaring it as a `Sub` instead makes this intention clear and doesn't leave it looking like a bug.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to call the incremented number directly in a function, this solution works bettter:

```
Function inc(ByRef data As Integer)
    data = data + 1
    inc = data
End Function
```

for example:

```
Wb.Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(myRow, inc(myCol))
```

If the function `inc()` returns no value, the above line will generate an error.

Comment: Your implementation is a prefix increment ++myCol. It returns the incremented value.
If you want postfix (myCol++) then the function should be looking like this:
`Function inc(ByRef data As Integer)
    inc = data
    data = data + 1
End Function`